# Customizing Android OS best practice

Tags: android, git, version-control

We need to customize the Android OS for our hardware specifications and design requirements. The source is hosted on http://source.android.com. The source is around 6 GB in size.

Assuming we need private repositories for our org, what is the best practice to follow here? Should we check out the entire code base and import it to our repository and then make changes there, or could we do something like git fork? Also, if we need to import the entire code base, we need huge disk space from our hosting provider (say, github) which becomes simply too expensive.